# ruby on rails : How can I make "rc.local" run when reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-14.04

This is what in my rc.local.

```
sh /var/www/test.sh   
exit 0
```

This is what in my test.sh

```
cd /home/jeff/test && rails s Puma -d
```

The problem is that rmv can't be found and ruby is in the usr/bin(1.9.3). My ruby  correct version is 2.1.5. How do I solve this problem?

maybe I should add path to test.sh, but I can't figure out how to let it recognize ruby 2.1.5 's path.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an answer myself.
In the rc.local file, I wrote this below.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
cd /home/jeff/thingspeak@
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
source $(rvm 2.1.0 do rvm env --path)
rvm use 2.1.5
sh   /var/www/thingspeak@/rails.sh

exit 0
```